Power of unit root tests
I am testing the power of basic unit root tests: ADF, PP and DFGLS.
In particular I am generating this sequence:
$$y_t = \text{drift} + (\text{trend_coeff} \cdot t) + (\phi \cdot y_{t-1}) + e_t$$
For a range of $\phi$ between 0 and 1, both inclusive.
Mathematically this yields From [0,1) a trend stationary process:

And at $\phi$ = 1, it yields a process with a stochastic trend:

Performing any unit root test on $\phi = [0,1)$ should reject the null and accept stationarity and at $\phi = 1$ it should accept the null of unit-root.
Expectation: By plotting the p values from the results one should expect to see for $\phi = [0,1)$ low pvalues (at least lower than significance level) since this would reject null for unit root tests, and for see $\phi = 1$ large pvalues (at least larger than significance level) since this means accept the null.
Results:
ADF and ADFGLS both use "AIC", PP uses Newey-West estimator for lag selection.
Number of samples: 300
drift=30
trend_coeff=10
sigma=20
number of simulations = 20

The question: What could be the reason for ADF-GLS returning that bell curve? Is it not supposed to be an improved version of ADF?
Note: I am using DFGLS from Arch lib in python.

Coming back to this, I think the answer is just that: The DF-GLS test has higher power than the ADF test when the autoregressive root is large but less than one. That is, the DF-GLS has a higher probability of rejecting the false null of a stochastic trend when the sample data stems from a time series that is close to being integrated."
This is what we see above, phi being between 0.8 and 1, so close to be integrated I(1), and dfgls returning high p values, i.e. accepting the null of unit root test.
In fact these type of tests are classified as efficient unit root tests,
and "they can have substantially higher power than the ADF or PP unit
root tests especially when φ is close to unity"[https://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ584/notes/unitroot.pdf]
